# Entering data into a json file step by step

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

To begin with, I'm a complete zero in javascript, so my question or code is likely to be terrible, but please stay calm.

This program was supposed to create a new text channel in which you would create a character with questions like "enter the name of the character:". And you wrote the character's name to the channel, and later it had to be saved so that after all the questions, all the character's data could be entered and separated into Json file. Character database in general.

My code:

```
...

const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#1EBF8B')
    .addFields(
    { name: `enter character's name`, value: `**name** **surname**` },
    )




    const Ageembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#1EBF8B')
    .addFields(
    { name: `enter character's age`, value: `**age**` },
    )
    

    const Raceembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#1EBF8B')
    .addFields(
    { name: `enter character's race:`, value: `**race**` },
    )


    const bioembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#1EBF8B')
    .addFields(
    { name: `enter biography: `, value: `**. . .**` },
    )


    const linkembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#1EBF8B')
    .addFields(
    { name: `enter image link`, value: `**http://..**` },
    )




    message.guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}`, {
        type: 'text',
        permissionOverwrites: [
           {
             id: everyone.id,
             deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
          },
          {
              id: message.author.id,
              allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
          }
        ],
      }) 
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      .then(channel => {
        let channelx = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel.id)
        let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        channelx.send(exampleEmbed);
        channelx.awaitMessages(filter, {
         max: 1,
        time: 60000,
        errors: ['time']
    
    
    }).then(message => {

        umessage = message.first()
        let uargs = umessage.content.trim().split(/ +/);
    
        var Name1 = uargs[0]
        var Surname1 = uargs[1]
        console.log(Name1 + ' ' + Surname1 )




    
    }).then(channel => {
        channelx.send(Ageembed);
        channelx.awaitMessages(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 60000,
            errors: ['time']


        }).then(message => {
            umessage = message.first()
            let uargs = umessage.content.trim().split(/ +/);
           
            var Age1 = uargs[0]
           console.log(Age1)


        }).then(channel => {
            channelx.send(Raceembed);
            channelx.awaitMessages(filter,{
                max: 1,
                time: 60000,
                errors: ['time']
            })
            
           .then(message => {
            umessage = message.first()
            let uargs = umessage.content.trim().split(/ +/);
           
           
           
           var Race1 = uargs[0]
           console.log(Race1)
           
           }).then(channel => {
            channelx.send(bioembed);
            channelx.awaitMessages(filter,{
             max: 1,
             time: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
             errors: ['time']
            })
            
            
            .then(message => {
             umessage = message.first()
             let uargs = umessage.content.trim()
            
            
            
            var Bio1 = uargs
            console.log(Bio1)
            
            }).then(channel => {
                channelx.send(linkembed);
                channelx.awaitMessages(filter,{
                 max: 1,
                 time: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
                 errors: ['time']

                }).then(message => {
                    umessage = message.first()
                    let uargs = umessage.content.trim()
                   
                    var Link1 = uargs
                    console.log(Link1)
                   
                }).then(channel => {

                    character[message.author.id] = {
                        name: Name1,
                        surname: Surname1,
                        age: Age1,
                        race: Race1,
                        bio: Bio1,
                        link: Link1

                    }
                    try {
                        fs.writeFileSync('../characters.json', JSON.stringify(character));
                      } catch(err) {
                        console.error(err);
                      }

                })
                
            })
            
            })

           })
       })
})
       
...
```

and json file should contains data like

```
{"id here":{"name":...,"surname":...}}
```

etc.

Simply put, after each response, using the .then () function, it moves to a new action. But, apparently, at the end it cannot find "name1", "surname1", etc. that the user entered.

but as expected nothing works.
The bot creates a channel, sends messages to it, receives them back, but dies at the moment when it is time to write data to a json file. That is, at the end.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Name1 is not defined

I think I understand what the error is, but I don't have a single solution to this problem

It can be done easier, right?

Thanks if you took the time to figure this out!

Comment: Break your code down, focus on the problem/error and not post your whole code basis here. The error message is pretty clear: `Name1 is not defined` You have scoping problem.

Comment: @Raffon That dosnt help him. @NeArdit has not defined `Name1` in the callback where he tries to access it. Its a scope problem and has not per sé anything to do with json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Name1` variable is in another scope, which means it doesn't exist where you are trying to access it. To avoid this, you could declare that variable at the very beginning of your code, then reassign it's value later. Also, you don't need to have so many `.then()` chains. There exists async/await which is exactly to prevent that.